# what is difference between xcorr and cross corr in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new in signal processing.  I want to check the relation between the two wind speed data at different location. i am not getting whether which matlab command I have to use whether it is 'xcorr' or 'cross corr' in matlab ?

Comment: Many answers to this question can be found in the Matlab Central forum. Like: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316589 I would start with `xcorr`.

Answer (score 1):

While [`xcorr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) calculates the Correlation between 2 vectors (By the way, doing it using `fft` and not `conv`) [`crosscorr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/crosscorr.html) calculates the Statistics Correlation, namely by removing the means of the samples and standardization:

output = <(x - mean(x)), (y - mean(y))> / (|x| * |y|)

If the vectors which are the input to the functions are centered (Namely with Zero Mean) and normalized they will be equal.

Comment: I had two time series which already had mean zero, but these two command give different result for same lag.

Comment: Could you post the code? I looked into the code of both, basically, the compute the XCF the same using FFT where `crosscorr` just do a pre processing step of centering the data.

Comment: Ok, I missed the normalization in `crosscorr`. Just like in "Normalized Cross Correlation" here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation.

Answer (score -1):

They should be the same but `crosscorr` also plots the result.